# How to restrict access to S3 hosted website using VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a simple website hosted on `aws` `s3`. And currently it is being accessible by anyone.

But I need to restrict the access.

So, I have an `aws` `client vpn endpoint` setup with the CIDR block of `10.3.0.0/22`

So is it possible to give access only to anyone who's ONLY connected to VPN and restrict the access anything else.

Answer (score 1):

We can restrict S3 access to certain ip range. [Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-s3-traffic-vpc-ip/) are some examples.

Requests to S3 is allowed only when sourceIp falls under `10.3.0.0/22`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-static-assets-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "10.3.0.0/22"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is good, but sometimes back I couldn't access by bucket even from the aws console as my IP changed. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @JananathBanuka Access to S3 bucket to AWS console users is better controlled via IAM Policies and Roles, than individual bucket resource policies. I typically use bucket polices to provide access to cross accounts or non-aws users, in this case it is general public.

Comment: The problem is when I add a source IP like this, if the IP has changed, I can't even access the `s3` bucket through console as well. I had to ask the `root` user to delete the policy even though I had full `s3` access. Is it possible to provide s3 access to a whole account? so anyone logged into that account has the ability to access the s3 bucket.

Comment: unable to get this solution to work